# pandas convert two columns of strings with square brackets to dictionary with list as key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Sample data frame which are strings with square brackets (like lists).

```
name         items
['A', 'B']   ['1', 2', 3']. (data type is strings for these apparent lists)
```

Expected result:

```
dict1 = {['1', '2', '3']:['A', 'B']}
```

I made several attempts including converting the columns using .apply(ast.literal_eval).  Still results in something like this when attempting to convert the column above using tolist():

```
[['A', 'B']]
```

Perhaps a dict cannot be created in this way given the data type for the columns is string?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You can't have `['1','2','3']` as a dict key because it is immutable (hence unhashable). For string `"['1','2','3']"` though, you can do: `dict(zip(df['items']), df['names]))`

Comment: What about just converting each column to individual lists and then I could zip together, one by one, each item in the one list the whole list in the other item?

Comment: Yes, you can have `{'1': ['A','B'], '2': ['A','B'],...}` or you can also have `{('1','2','3'): ['A','B']}` because tuple is immutable.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks so much for responding.  Any idea why using .tolist() on a column does this:  My column is a string like this ['A', 'B'].  When I apply .tolist() to it I get:  ['['A', 'B']'].  Those outside quote marks and then the final square brackets.

Comment: because `tolist` convert the *whole* column to a big list, not converting *each cell* to a list.

Comment: Right.  What I want is the column to be converted to a list of lists in which each item of the list is an individual row of that one column.